# jQuery table on click for rows grabs table headers aswell

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have a function in my vue application that is done when a table row is clicked here :

```
$("#connectionsTable tr").click(function () {
  var list = [];
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),
  $tds = $row.find("td");
  // console.log($tds);
  // list.push({ name: $tds.eq(0).text(), numSongs: $tds.eq(1).text(), Year: $tds.eq(2).text() });
  list.push({ connectionName: $tds.eq(0).text(), host: $tds.eq(1).text(), port: $tds.eq(2).text(), serviceName: $tds.eq(2).text() });
   // self.$store.state.tableRow = list;
   self.setConnectionTableRow(list);
   self.$router.push('/analytic-two');
});
```

Is there a way i can write the function that excludes the table header as one of the on click functions any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Your table header row is in a `thead` as per the HTML spec, right?

Comment: `$("#connectionsTable tbody tr")` will do, assuming you have wrapped headers in `thead`

Comment: Can you show you template code also , because you can do it the vuejs way by setting up click listeners only on `<tr>` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, make sure your table header is in the correct `thead` and the body is in a `tbody` and then the selector simply becomes:

```
$("#connectionsTable tbody tr").click(function () { ... } )
```

Live example below.

```js
$('table tbody tr').click(function(){
    console.log("click on body");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Header1</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Cell</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to header row like `class="header-row"` and add `return false` after checking that row [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass) `header-row` like,

```
$("#connectionsTable tr").click(function () {
   if($(this).hasClass('header-row'))
      return false; // getting header row, so return from here without executing other statements
   var list = [];
   ....
});
```

Alternatively, You can exclude header-row by using [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector) like,

```
$("#connectionsTable tr:not(.header-row)").click(function () {
   var list = [];
   ....
});
```

Comment: Why not just do `tr:not(.header-row)` as the selector if you're not interested in that element(s)?

Comment: `$("#connectionsTable tr:not(.header-row)")` would be better selector